# What is the expectation of a change in Brownian motion?

Tags: brownian-motion, expected-value

I know $E[W_T-W_t]=0$ but I have a solution which implies this is wrong.

### Question

[image: Question]

### Answer

[image: Answer]

Comment: This question was originally closed for being too basic. I'd like to point to the subtlety of expectations as beautifully explained out by the accepted answer. I think this is important and could confuse other students in the field.

Also, this site has a popular question on annualizing the Sharpe Ratio. If that question is sophisticated enough, so is knowing that, "E(X)=μ doesn't necessarily imply E[f(X)]=f(μ)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X)=\mu$ doesn't necessarily imply $E[f(X)]=f(\mu)$. In this case, if $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $e^X \sim lnN(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (lognormal distribution) and $$E(e^X)=e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$$. We know that $W_T-W_t \sim N(0,T-t)$ therefore $\sigma\gamma(W_T-W_t) \sim N(0,\sigma^2\gamma^2(T-t))$.
It is easy to see that $$E[e^{\sigma\gamma(W_T-W_t)}]=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\gamma^2(T-t)}$$